# Regular expression for deleting string after a character

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file with about 1000 lines and want to delete eerything after a character on each line in notepad++. Example of format:

```
text=more text
text=more text
text=more text
text=more text
text=more text
```

I want to delete all text after the = on each line so the output would be:

```
text=
text=
text=
text=
text=
```

I have tried numerous expressions but cant seem to get it to work.I have tried:

```
Find what: =.*
Replace with:
```

and it doesn't work

Comment: If text is of constant width, column-select + delete

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the "=", you have to put it into your replacement string:

```
Find what: =.*
Replace with: =
```

Otherwise, everything after the `=` including the `=` would be deleted.

As a side node, I prefer to explicitly use the end anchor `$` in regular expressions:

```
Find what: =.*$
Replace with: =
```

(Although that is not strictly needed as the `*` operator is greedy by default.)

Answer (score 0):

```
^.*?=\K.*
```

You can use `\K` over here.This way evrything upto `=` will be saved and rest deleted.See demo.Replace with `empty string`

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/15

Comment: This regex is twice less efficient than vog's.